# How to make \documentclass{book} fit in A4

Tags: geometry

I am writing PhD thesis by using a book-template which allow me to use "Part" and easier to create different sections (need English and German titles) under \frontmatter. The main preamble is set as:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
```

However, I wish to make it fit A4 size and all pages appearing evenly (they now appear odd and even like a book to print).
Further, the page numbers show differently in odd and even pages, like this

[image]

How can I make them in the same style?

Comment: With `\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}`, that's all.

Comment: if you do not want the default layout for two sided printing use `[12pt,a4paper,oneside]` then all pages will use the same layout (as if for an odd numbered page)

Comment: also remove the line `\usepackage[total={6in, 8in}]{geometry} `  which is specifying a different page size, in inches.

Answer (score 2):

Change the first line to `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}` to make generate it in A4 size.